# 100% completion of Batman: Arkham City

Tags: batman-arkham-city

Is there any reward for 100 percent completion of Batman: Arkham City, including all Riddler challenges and new game plus?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [Perfect Knight - Day 2](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/batman-arkham-city/achievement/57327-Perfect-Knight---Day-2.html) for 360. There are equivalent achievements on the PS3 and PC (through Steam) as well.

Entire list of achievements (for 360): http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/batman-arkham-city/achievements/

Comment: Was hoping for a new suit or something but ok thanks, just got the challenges left now :)